# Wlan on Acer Aspire E11

Tags: wireless, acer

I have just bought a Acer Aspire E11 Netbook.
I have installed different Ubuntu Distros
but on all Distros there is no WLan Client availbale.
I have also installed Win 8.1 which connects via WLan flawlessly.
Is there anything I can do about it?

Thanks
Franl

Comment: Please edit your question to include details of your wireless device. Open a terminal and run and post: lspci -nn | grep 0280 Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The result of this Bash Command:                  02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)

Answer (score 1):

Please obtain a temporary internet connection, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Reboot and your wireless should be working.

NOTE: This technique is valid for Ubuntu 14.04 and later. If your version is different, I urge you to upgrade.

You can try to coax your ethernet to connect with:

```
sudo ethtool -s eth0 speed 100 duplex full autoneg off
```

Then see if Network Manager can connect and install the wireless package as above.

Comment: Thanks for your help.                                                                                              Unfortunately I can`t obtain any internet connection, tried it via Network Wire, sharing my mobile connection via USB. Is there a way around it? A quick fix  which makes my wired connection work?

Comment: What is your ethernet device? lspci -nn | grep 0200 Thanks.

Comment: My Ethernet Device:                                                        03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)

Comment: Please see my edit above.